STS 4+ with JFrog & JXray plugins bundled opinions, is this combination available
STS 4+ with JFrog & JXray plugins bundled opinions for JDK11, is this combination available? Where can I have it?
Since my company is mandating JFrog Artifactory rather than Open Maven Central Repository due to Security grounds. They are also disabling Eclipe  Marketplace due to the same reason.
Is there any way bridging STS4.7.2 & latest JFrog & JXray plug-in pre-installed. Is there anyway I could get STS 4.7.2 + JFrog & JXray plug-ins pre-installed?
This combination is supposed to make Azure pipeline code build validation in local Workstation. I am trying for JFrog CLI by Powershell, which didn't make it due to the same security blockade.
I am a Maven evangelist, but not in my current role with all the above whistle blowings.
Could you kindly share any links or pointers to refer or link to look for consideration or kind of give it a try. Since JFrog + JXray plug-in stuff is licensed & I doubt that I will get it in any IDE plug-in.

There is JFrog Artifactory extension in the Azure DevOps marketplace.  Do you use a self-hosted agent when doing Azure pipeline code build validation? If you use a Microsoft hosted agent, is it also restricted for security reasons?
